# PhoneGap + iFrame : Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: iframe, cookies, cordova

I'm trying to resolve a bug, but i can't.

My problem is : 
In my phonegap application, i need to integrate an iframe (I can't give my url for safety reasons). My iframe is displayed but i have an error message.

The iframe try to setCookies on the device and read it. If i launch the iframe on safari directly or if i use InAppBrowser of Phonegap, i have no problem/error. But through phonegap "iframe", I get an error.

The log are :

> Blocked a frame with origin "http:// URL_IFRAME:NUMBER_PORT" from accessing a frame with origin "file://". The requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.

I hope to be fairly accurate.
Thks

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837354/chrome-blocks-different-origin-requests

Comment: Thank you for the link, but the subject deals with a problem of cross-origin content. My iframe is displayed, co I am not sure that is the problem. 
I have an error from javascript : "Unexepected exception in logging detection, using default: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object".

Comment: Different protocols ( `http` / `file` ) are the worst case of cross-origin content.

Comment: Ok, but if i have a cross-origin content problem : the iframe isnt displayed ?

Comment: yes , `Blocked a frame with origin` : It cannot be more clear

Comment: I'm agree with you, but when i launch my function i have in my console log this error "Blocked a frame with..." and a popup message "Unexepected except...." but when i clicke on the OK button from the popupr the frame is correctly displayed!. So what is wrong ? In any case, thank you for your answers

Comment: If you have config file , add this `<access origin="*"/>`.