# Remote Upload (using blueimp file upload plugin)

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, same-origin-policy, blueimp

Remote upload: Upload files via a given URL.

I want to add a remote upload to my website using `blueimp` plugin.
I found this link:https://gist.github.com/blueimp/5075976, but I use an external server to upload my files, so when I write this code, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://myExternalURL.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.myMainWebsite.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

The part of the code with the url:

```
$('#remote-file-copy').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).find('input').val(),
        iframe = $('<iframe src="javascript:false;" style="display:none;"></iframe>');
    if (url) {
        iframe
            .prop('src', 'http://I-USE-EXTERNAL-URL/remote-file-copy.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url))
            .appendTo(document.body);
    }
});
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you very much!
and sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line right after `<?php` in `remote-file-copy.php`

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

this will tell the browser to allow javascript from other origins to access content from your php file , if you only want to allow from your site you can also do this:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourmaindomain.com");
```

more reading on this:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)
,[enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html), [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

see also : [chrome-blocks-different-origin-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837354/chrome-blocks-different-origin-requests)

Comment: the error message you gave is related to cross domain origin , the code i gave you should work for ajax calls from domain A to domain B but in case of iframe take a look at [iframe cross domain javascript calls](http://madskristensen.net/post/iframe-cross-domain-javascript-calls) , seems like a good article to give you some clues .

Comment: @ArielAharonson btw the code generating error is Javascript inside iframe , (perhaps one that includes `window.parent`) not the code you posted , if you did the document.domain trick in the article i linked to and it still doesn't works post that code . if you can't make a subdomain as suggested in madskristensen's blog you should perhaps use a [php proxy](https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy) or don't use an iframe at all (perhaps put all js code in maindomain and check progress with jsonp?).

Comment: @ArielAharonson can you post your solution? I'm also having the same problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @AkoSiAsiong Look at the answer. You need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the remote server