# How can I execute function from the xhtml with frame?

Tags: javascript, iframe

As shown at diagram, how can I execute sample function in the x application?

http://imageshack.com/a/img834/52/xvso.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homework? See [invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/).

In your case:

```
document.getElementById('test-iframe').contentWindow.sample(args);
```

Comment: not homework. yes window.parent work butI am getting browser error. "SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://10.0.0.97:8082" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Comment: if you can, serve both from the same domain. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837354/chrome-blocks-different-origin-requests