# Unable to print the pdf loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page with button and IFRAME. Inside IFRAME, I am loading a PDF file dynamically which is coming from different domain.

when I try to print file using the button action I am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.cplusplus.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

If I load the pdf file from my local system I am to print it .

I used the below code to print the iframe Pdf

```
var iframe = document.querySelector("#unofficialtranscript");
iframe.focus();
iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

Any idea how I can print the file which is loaded into the iframe which is on another domain .

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to have a look at the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript#Changing_origin).Javascript only calls a window or an iframe only if the policy is accepted.

You may need to use [Postmessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) instead.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837354/chrome-blocks-different-origin-requests).

Comment: I am seeing lot of example to send message using Postmessage api from main page to IFRAME,but my case is different that need to print the file.I am not sure how to do

Answer (score 0):

If both the parent DOM and child DOM (i.e., iframe) are from same domain then it will work fine.

If not, then use libraries like Porthole for cross-communication between different domains.

Demo site: http://sandbox.ternarylabs.com/porthole/

Note: You should have access to both the domains being used in your code.